# Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: on importing a eclipse project

Tags: android

I have imported a project in Android Studio. I am attempting to run the code but the app fails with the following errors, not sure what the problem is.

These are the libraries i am using.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
compile files('libs/Android-WebRequest.jar')
compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.6.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.20.0.jar')

compile files('libs/google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev200-1.20.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.20.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')

compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile files('libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_answers-classes.jar')
compile files('libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_beta-classes.jar')
compile files('libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics-classes.jar')
compile files('libs/io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric-classes.jar')
```

and error i am getting is

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\ch-e01062\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.0-preview\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\ch-e01062\Downloads\FreeB2\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\ch-e01062\Downloads\FreeB2\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

i have tried many available solutions but nothing is working.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please make sure that none of the library should repeat again in your dependency list.

Comment: i know that...according to me i have not repeated any...i have pasted all the dependencies..plz let me know if you can find where i am wrong..

Answer (score 1):

After hours with the same problem i found the answer.

The problem is that you have multiple libs with the same classes inside, so the solution would be to either remove the repeating files from one of the libs.

You have to:

1. Open the lib `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar` with WinRAR, 7Zip or whatever.
2. Go to `com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal` and delete the files `Command$1.class` and `Command.class`.

In your case you may have to remove other repeating files, not sure because you have many files. Either way, you can also force it to ignore some of those files **IF** the method above didn't work. Put the following code inside the Android block on your build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```